# wenzhixin bootstrap-table detailView expanded by default

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using [Bootstrap Table](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/) with a table with the possibility to show the detailed view by pressing the plus button on the left. I am looking for a way to make the expanded detail view the default behaviour and use the minus sign to collapse the data. I can't find any solution on the API.  I am populating the table using jinja and Flask so I would like the find a solution that works with the following code.

```
<table id="table"
        data-toggle="table"
        data-filter-control="true"
        data-show-search-clear-button="true"
        data-sortable="true"
        classes="table-sm"
        data-pagination="true"
        data-show-columns="true"
        data-show-columns-toggle-all="true"
        class="table-responsive"
        
        data-toolbar="#toolbar"
        data-search="true"
        data-show-refresh="true"
        data-show-toggle="true"
        data-show-fullscreen="true"
        data-show-columns="true"
        data-show-columns-toggle-all="true"
        data-detail-view="true"
        data-show-export="true"
        data-click-to-select="true"
        data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
        data-minimum-count-columns="2"
        data-show-pagination-switch="true"
        data-pagination="true"
        data-id-field="id"
        data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, all]"
        data-show-footer="true"
        >
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th data-field="link" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true" data-visible="false">asdf</th>
              <th data-field="asdf" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true" data-visible="false">asdf</th>
                <!--special characters and spaces not allowed in data-field name-->
                <th data-field="asdf" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">asdf</th>
                <th data-field="asdf" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">asdf</th>
                <th data-field="asdf" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">asdf </th>
                <th data-field="asdf" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true" data-visible="false">asdf</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for row in tableA %}
          <tr>
              
              <!--non visibili  -->
              <td>{{row['asdf']|safe}}</td>
              <td>{{ row['asdf'][0]['asdf'] }}</td>
              <!--special characters and spaces not allowed in data-field name-->
              <td>{{ row['asdf'][0]['df'] }}</td>
              <td>{{ row['sdf'][0]['asdf'] }}</td>
              <td>{{ row['asdf'][0]['asdf'] }}</td>
              <td>{{url_for('asdf', asdf=row['asdf'])}}</td>

          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

So far this is the only solution I came up with, that worked for me, at least before the user query the table.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    window.onload = setTimeout(function() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("detail-icon");
    x.forEach(element =>element.click())
    }, 1000);
  });
```